# How to install LoopBack-API-Explorer into existing application

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I'm following the official "Getting Started"-tutorial of LoopBack: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Use-API-Explorer.html

Everything works fine apparently. However, when it comes to open the API-Explorer in a webbrowser, it gives 404:

> 404 Cannot GET /explorer

This is working as expected: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

This returns 404 status code: http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer

Is it lack of documentation or some incampatibilities between Tutorial and newest loopback-generator?

I did every step exactly as mentioned in the tutorial.

Maybe this config-file called "server/config.json" can help, because i stumbled upon a setting "legacyExplorer":false.

Or is it necessary to install the explorer as a separated component?

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": false,
    "handleErrors": false
  },
  "legacyExplorer": false
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tutorial comes with two different cli-tools for creating the application stack: apic and slc.

I bet that you were using **apic** and I'm pretty sure that this tutorial would work out of the box if you would use **slc** to create all these boilerplate instead of **apic**.

To make it run in your apic-based setup, just install the api-explorer.

```
npm install --save loopback-component-explorer --save
```

and register the route as follows:

In the directory-structure from root-folder there is a folder called "server". Create an empty file named "component-config.json" into the "server" folder and place the following code inside:

```
{
  "loopback-component-explorer": {
    "mountPath": "/explorer"
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to open the explorer-page with the url http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer.